# Move feature(s) causes points to be duplicated in QGIS 2.8.9

Tags: qgis, vector, point

I have a point shapefile in QGIS where I am manually adjusting some of the points due to overlap. I am using Toggle editing --> Move feature(s) --> Save for all layers. Instead of moving the points these are duplicated. The original point stays where it is, in addition an extra point is created wherever I move it to. This does not seem to lead to any any additional entries in the attribute table.

Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting. I tried the same in 2.8.7 and everything works as expected. Do you have write access to your shapefile, is it opened anywhere else or sth?

Comment: I have write access, and it is not open anywhere else.

Comment: Is it possible that the shapefile is corrupt? Could you make a copy of the shapefile via rightclick > save as.. and try again with the copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have multiple points stacked on top of each other.  Try dragging a selection box over a point and check the attribute table to see how many features you have selected.  If it really is duplicating then you might want to update QGIS to a newer version (2.14) and try it again.

Comment: I had an older version of QGIS on a different laptop, and this worked as expected.